# How to use where in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use where in linq 
the error says can't implicitly convert type string to xx.modules.Students

here is my code

```
Students student = new Students();
int userId = Convert.ToInt16(InputAPIVM.USERID);
student = db.Students.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToString();
```

Comment: why `.ToString()`?

Comment: Remove the `ToString()`. 
`Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` (in your case, the `T` is probably a class called `Student`.

Comment: Try student = db.Students.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).Select(x => x.UserId).FirstOrDefault();  You need to get just the userId and only one.  The Where returns and array of all the properties in X.

Comment: @jdweng Why provide an answer in comments if there are already equal answers?

Comment: Ok,
but this code must return more than one column

Comment: Your code (without the .ToString()) returns a `Student` object.  That /is/ multiple columns.  If you want the student name, I presume there is a Student.Name property?

Comment: @Neil No, an enumerable containing (at most) one instance of `Student`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yeah, or course.  But still that single `Student` object does contain said properties.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman : My comment was earlier than the answer.  Often two people answer a question simultaneously of within a couple of minutes of each other.

Comment: What is `new Students()`? Why `ToString`? Maybe you should acquire some basic skills first before asking questions about haphazard trial-and-error code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting one entry, you should get that entry, and not try to output an enumerable to string, as you do now:

```
student = db.Students.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).SingleOrDefault();
```

This can be simplified to:

```
student = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
```

Comment: You aren't returning a column, you are returning an instance with properties (aka columns).

Comment: student = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId).Select(x =>x.userId);

Comment: Then you are just selecting the ID, which is already in `userId`.

Comment: @NebroProgNebro Are you asking why it's not useful to select from the database a value you already have?

Comment: No, it returns one column and I do not need that

Comment: No, it returns one column and I do not need that

Comment: The code in my answer does not return one column, unless there is just one column in the data model.

Answer (score 0):

use `SingleOrDefault` to get a `Student` instead of `ToString()`

```
db.Students.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Student student = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(s => s.UserId == userId)
    ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"No single student for UserId {userId}.");
```

You can use `SingleOrDefault` - this returns the first student which matches the user id.

If there is no matching student then the default value for the Student type is returned. If Student is a `class` and not a `struct` then the default value is null - I assume this to be the case.

The [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) can be used to return a default student instance or raise a meaningful exception if no matching student (null) is returned.

This guards against you accidentally bumping into a null student when you don't expect it.

Comment: *If there is no matching student then the default value for the Student type is returned.* If you don't want that, use `Single()`.

Comment: Agree can be shortened - I find if I'm going to be throwing something, most of the time I want to provide a bit more context than the standard InvalidOperationException for that (added).